# What does "purificador sobre tarja" mean?

Tags: vocabulario, méxico

I live in Xalapa and am shopping for an inexpensive water filter that will do the job. I find one at Home Depot that looks alright, and I'm trying to get information on the type and its capabilities. However, there seems to be something lost in translation. *"Purificador sobre tarja"*? I don't find anything about "card purifiers" in English. **What does *"tarja"* mean?** Could it possibly mean "cartridge"?

Answer (score 2):

***Tarja*** (from French *[targe](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/targe#Etymology_3)*, "round shield") means "sink", that is, the bowl usually found in the kitchen in a house, together with the counter where it is installed and its water taps. Curiously this meaning can't be found [in the DLE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=ZCkZqPT). In the DAMER (*Diccionario de Americanismos*) the entry for *[tarja](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=tarja)* says it's a memorial plaque. This might or might not have something to do with its use in Mexico, if the plaque is a reference to the counter or else the round, concave shape of a shield can point to the shape of the sink. I don't know if *tarja* means "sink" elsewhere. In Spanish this is known more commonly as *fregadero* (and in Argentina and Paraguay it's *[bacha](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=bacha)*).

A water purifier can come prepared for installation as an appliance above the counter (*sobre tarja*) or hidden behind it (*bajo tarja*). (Pic from [here](http://mejoresacabados.mx/tarja-para-la-cocina-un-elemento-indispensable/).)

[image]

It seems the usual terms in English for these are "under-sink" and "over countertop".

Comment: counter top water filer.

Comment: Thanks for the fantastic graphic and explanation!